# Circular Doubly Linked List find length with single pointer

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-structures

I have pointer to circular doubly linked list with random values of 0 or 1.
Example: `[{prev,0,next},{prev,0,next},{prev,1,next},{prev,0,next}...]`
I have a single pointer to the first item of the list. 
I need to find the length of the list **without to create any additional pointers**.
In addition, I can change the values of each node between 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.

I thought about `Josephus Circle` algorithm - with no success.

My main problem is that I don't even know what end of a circle/circular list is.
If you think about that, you will understand it is not an easy question.

Comment: (`I don't know if I arrive to the end of the list` I don't even know what *end of a circle/circular list* is.) You may need to change direction, not limited to your thinking. It *may* help to think of Turing.

Comment: @greybeard I changed the direction. How can Turing help here?

Comment: Are you looking for *any algorithm at all*, no matter how efficient?  Do you have requirements on how efficient it must be?  Do you have a pointer to the start of the list (so you can keep a pointer to the start of the list and a separate pointer that you modify)?

Comment: I have a single pointer to the start of the list. But I can't add separate pointer. The efficienct should be the best it can

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Can you have one pointer that is to the start of the list and is never modified but can be read later, and a second pointer that you modify in each step of the algorithm?  Can you tell us where you encountered this problem?  Can you credit the original source of the problem?

Comment: *Thinking* of Turing may help: the possibilities to stay in place, move left or right, and set the value of the current cell to one of a finite set of values remind me of the machine model in his name. Then, there is the matter of *states*: can you "have", say, three *integers* big enough to represent three times the `length of the list`? `I changed the direction` How far have you got with detecting a cycle of length one? Length three?

Comment: @D.W I have single pointer. You can move with him to next and previous and also change the values but you can't use 2 different pointers.

Comment: `The efficienct should be the best it can` Now [AcId spelt out how to exploit alternating direction to pass over "known" contents](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/108576/19966): What *length* is that known contents? How does that length increase? What type of growth would make a significant difference in worst case speed? Can you prove a lower bound on worst case speed? [You are encouraged to answer your own question.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Is it OK to destroy the contents of the list?  Or at the end of the algorithm do we need to restore the contents of the list?  If we must restore its contents, are we allowed to use as much temporary storage as we want to save its contents, or is there a limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following algorithm would do it:

1. Start by setting the value in the first node to $1$.
2. Follow `next` pointers until you encounter a node with value $1$, while keeping a counter $c$ of how many nodes you have encountered.
3. Set the value of the node to $0$ and follow `prev` pointers for $c$ steps

   - If the value of the node (which should be the first node) is now $0$, the list has $c-1$ elements,
   - otherwise, follow `next` pointers for $c$ steps and continue with step 2.

Comment: @D.W. Are you sure? It's looks promising as you said.

Comment: @motis10, I was confused.  Sorry.

Comment: @AcId and complexity is O(n(n+1)) = O(n^2). Right?

Comment: In the worst case (when every node has value $1$) you cycle back an forth across the list in every step, so I would say that the worst time complexity is $\sum_{i = 1}^n 2 i = n (n + 1) = \mathcal{O}(n^2)$. In the best case (every node has the value $0$) we only go back through the list once, so the best case complexity is $2n$.

Answer (score 0):

[One of your comments](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108541/circular-doubly-linked-list-find-length-with-single-pointer#comment231780_108541) suggests that you are interested in an ‘efficient’ solution -
assuming a non-empty list correctly doubly linked:

0. let $toSet = 1$ and set current item to $0$

1. $toSet$ times, follow the $next$ link and set to $1$
2. $toSet - 1$ times, follow the $prev$ link
3. up to $toSet$ times,

   - follow the $prev$ link,
   - if item is $1$, the number of $prev$s followed since last change of direction is the number of items,
     else set to $1$
4. double $toSet$
5. $toSet$ times, follow the $prev$ link and set to $0$
6. $toSet - 1$ times, follow the $next$ link
7. up to $toSet$ times,

   - follow the $next$ link,
   - if item is $0$, the number of $next$s followed since last change of direction is the number of items,
     else set to $0$
8. double $toSet$ and repeat from 1

The number of items set and potentially inspected doubles with each "half-iteration".
The number of items checked is exactly the number $n$ of items in the list.
The number of items set varies from $3n-1$ for $n = 2^i$ to $2n$ for $n = 2^{i + 1} - 1$.

ToDo: find
a simple pattern of length growth between ("half-")iterations that works for every list length, too, *and*
a list length where *#sets + #follows + #compares* is smaller than for doubling as above

Comment: I do not believe your algorithm is correct. Running the algorithm on an example with a list of size $3$ gives the result $2$ in step $7)$.

Comment: @AcId: I had translated this to and from Java before posting. While 3 hasn't been one of my test cases, 1, 7, 8 and 9 were, in addition to larger ones. Just added 3 with no problem - how can we sort this out?

Comment: (Hm. One point where I thought I might/would get overly explicit is *number of $prev$s/$next$s followed*: since last change of direction, not start of procedure.)

Comment: Perhaps the Java code doesn't match what you've written here, as I also get a result 2 when running on a list of size 3.  First we do lines 0-3, and the list is [1,1,x].  After line 4, toSet = 2.  After line 6, the list is [1,0,0], and we're pointing at the last item in the list.  Step 7 first sets the list to [0,0,0], then terminates after following the second next link, and outputs 2.

Comment: (Found an envelope: no problem with symbolic execution using size 3. Dissatisfied with "ASCII-graphics" of the succession of states - seems easier when using a, b, and x for values and a capital for *current item*. Sufficiently confused when using *first item is current item* (moving the tape instead of the head).)

Comment: @ D.W. `the list is [1,1,x].` It should be [0, 1, x]: part of step 0 is *set current item to 0*.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://imgur.com/y0F2x03) to the full example written in $\LaTeX$ - perhaps I'm misinterpreting some of the steps, but I consistently get the result $2$.

Comment: (Had to "Accept" data skimming blurb.) Ah. You are not counting the *follow next* in 6). See [third comment: *followed since last change of direction*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108541/circular-doubly-linked-list-find-length-with-single-pointer/108641#comment232124_108641).

Comment: @greybeard : So in step $3$ (resp. $7$) you have to also count the links followed in step $2$ (reps. $6$)? I don not think this is very clear from your answer. Perhaps consider editing to make this point clear.

Comment: (@D.W. I now think I mis-read your `lines 0-3`, you probably meant what I('d) call *steps* (which may be multi-line/substep): at the end of the first "step-3 iteration", the contents is as [presented by you](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108541/circular-doubly-linked-list-find-length-with-single-pointer/108641#comment232136_108641).)

Comment: Over time, I had three noticeably different "pseudo code" representations of the algorithm, starting with a high-level *go back and forth over ranges of values doubling in length, checking how much of the previous range survived* over a detailed variant using a "direction" state to avoid essentially repeating half of the description, (a Java implementation where I found the repetition more readable and no longer,) and the one presented in this answer.